# Cache reference vs Cache access

Tags: performance, caching, architecture, cpu-architecture

I am a bit confused regarding the difference between " Number of Cache access " and " Number of Cache reference " during execution of a scientific application . Which one depends on the size of the cache (if it depends) ?

Could anyone please explain it.

Thanks and regards

Comment: I thought "access" and "reference" were typically used as synonyms, but it is possible that "reference" might include prefetches (which do not read or write the data and so might not technically count as accesses) while such might be excluded from the "access" count. The simulator or performance counter documentation should clarify.

Comment: Could it be the following mapping: hit == cache access; hit+miss == cache reference. In what context is this terminology mentioned?